# Do I need to have a passport for domestic flights in India after 22nd of January, 2018?

Tags: domestic-travel, air-india, connecting-flights

Prior to the 22nd January, there is no need to carry a passport for domestic flights in India, but what happens after that? Will you need to carry a passport after 22nd Jan, 2018 for domestic flights in India?

Comment: How did you arrive at the date - 22/Jan/2018? Is there an official govt. notification for this date or a news item? Can you update the question with appropriate link?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, no individual needs to adjust their travel plans, or rush out to get a new driver's license or passport for domestic air travel.

If you are an Indian citizen, passports are not mandatory.

For domestic travel within India, valid photo identification namely a passport, Aadhar Card, Income Tax PAN Card, Voter's ID or Driving license is mandatory. Any other relevant concessionary fare IDs should be carried as they need to be produced if required.

As of now there's no information regarding the necessity of passports after 22nd Jan, 2018 for domestic travel. If that changes, I will update this answer.

Comment: Thanx!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer was helpful to you, please up-vote my answer which will help other people in the future as well..